# Line (from gpx) intersects polygon (from Fusion Table)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I decide to get administrative area from Fusion Tables. After import gpx file I save it into MySQL

```php
$gpx = simplexml_load_file($folder.$file);
$trasa ="'LINESTRING(";
foreach ($gpx->trk->trkseg->trkpt as $trkpt) {
    $lat = (string) $trkpt['lat'];
    $lon = (string) $trkpt['lon'];
    $trasa .= $lon;
    $trasa .=" ";
    $trasa .= $lat;
    $trasa .=",";
}
$trasa =rtrim($trasa,",");
$trasa .=")',0";
unset($gpx);
$ins = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO punktytras(nick,punkty) VALUES('$nick', LineFromText($trasa))");
```

After that i wish to load on map Fusion Table layer  intersects with gpx line by code

```js
    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: {
            select: 'geometry',
            from: '1w7Z-O1F0g4s2suHq4mSlAJ-31MBPwVLB7vXKAuaY',
            where: 'SELECT ST_INTERSECTS(LineFromText($trasa), geometry))'
          }
        });
  layer.setMap(map);
```

but all geometry from Fusion Table are loaded. Where I made mistake? TIA 4 answers.

edited
OK, I change my query, now I have

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "uploads/<?php echo $row['file'] ?>",
     dataType: "xml",
     success: function(xml) {
       var points = [];
        var kolory=[];
       $(xml).find("trkpt").each(function() {
         var lat = $(this).attr("lat");
         var lon = $(this).attr("lon");
         var p = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
            var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: {
            select: '\'geometry\'',
            from: '1w7Z-O1F0g4s2suHq4mSlAJ-31MBPwVLB7vXKAuaY',
            where: 'ST_INTERSECTS(\'geometry\',CIRCLE(LATLNG('+ lat+","+lon +'), 0.5));'
          }
        });
        layer.setMap(map);
        points.push(p);
         bounds.extend(p); 

       });
```

But i think that I have only 5 Fusion Tables Layers for first 5 ponts from my gpx. I have no idea, how can I first select areas contains points from gpx, and after that add them as a FTLayer :(

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not valid:

```
where: 'SELECT ST_INTERSECTS(LineFromText($trasa), geometry))'
```

The first parameter needs to be a column name from your table.  Lines are not supported (currently) as the geometry.

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/sql-reference#returns):

**ST_INTERSECTS**

> - `<spatial_condition>`
>
> Used in the WHERE clause. The syntax is: ST_INTERSECTS(`<location_column>`, `<geometry>`)
>
> ST_INTERSECTS cannot be combined with ORDER BY ST_DISTANCE.

---

> - `<geometry>`
>
> Use one of the following:
>
> `<circle>`
> `<rectangle>`
>
> - `<location_column>` A `<column_name>` for the column in your table that contains location data.

Comment: Thanks 4 answer geocodezip

So, should I use

'where: 'SELECT ST_INTERSECTS( geometry,($trasa2))''
where $trasa2 could be a rectangle build from $trasa?

or use 'google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(PointFromText(concat("POINT(",$lat," ",lon,")")), geometry)' for each point? What is the better way to find Polygons intersects with Line in your opinion?

Comment: Mayby put gpx also into Fusion Table is correct way?